# Python: Convert a list of dictionaries into a JSON object

Tags: python

Convert:

```
[{"name": "name 1", "course": "course 1"}, {"name": "name 2", "course": "course 2"}]
```

Into:

```
{{"name": "name 1", "course": "course 1"}, {"name": "name 2", "course": "course 2"}}
```

How to do this conversion?

Comment: Whats the key in the second one? No key no dict

Comment: otherwise its ```import json json.loads(l)```

Comment: Neither of those two examples are valid json, though the top is closer (the single quotes would need to be double quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

l = [{'name': 'name 1', 'course': 'course 1'}, {'name': 'name 2', 'course': 'course 2'}]
d = {'student': l}
json_l = json.dumps(d)
```

```
json_l
Out[3]: '{"students": [{"name": "name 1", "course": "course 1"}, {"name": "name 2", "course": "course 2"}]}'
```

```
{
   "students":[
      {
         "name":"name 1",
         "course":"course 1"
      },
      {
         "name":"name 2",
         "course":"course 2"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: your example is still not a fully working json. either each "student" gets a key, or it is as in my example ```{"student": [{student1}, {student2}]```

Comment: Please now check.

Comment: Here you can check if your output is a valid json https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Mine is, yours not yet

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have used link https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com. It helps me in solving my problem.